# O que fazem os módulos de segurança comumente usados em sites de bancos?

Tags: java, segurança, navegador-de-internet

A maioria dos bancos oferecem algum tipo de módulo de segurança que atua do lado do cliente para acesso aos sites de internet banking. Geralmente são feitos em Java e costumam ser bem chatos de instalar.

O que exatamente eles fazem, no nível técnico? Contra o que eles estão protegendo? Se existe alguma ameaça de que eles protegem, por que isso não é usado em todos os sites e, por fim, vem integrado em todos os navegadores? Por que o uso de Java em vez de, por exemplo, uma extensão de navegador?

Comment: É mais um grande marketing do que uma solução verdadeira. Já fiz vários testes com clonagem de MAC, cópia de dados "escondidos" em lugares estratégicos, e tenha a certeza que é relativamente simples burlar estes sistemas (tanto que tem banco sério que não instala nada pra netbanking, e vai bem). Por outro lado, a dor de cabeça que isso dá para clientes comuns é uma desgraça. A solução dos módulos geralmente é atrasada em relação aos browsers, e muitas vezes larga serviços e tarefas rodando desnecessariamente nos clientes, além de conflitos com aplicações já instaladas em alguns casos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Há uns dois anos tive problemas com o Módulo de Segurança do Banco do Brasil e fiz algumas pesquisas sobre o assunto. Já aviso que não sou especialista em segurança, nem tenho conhecimento sobre o funcionamento interno desses softwares.

## O que são os Módulos de Segurança

Cada banco tem uma solução, portanto vou limitar minha resposta ao Banco do Brasil.

Segundo [referência do próprio banco](http://www.bb.com.br/portalbb/page3,105,5564,0,0,1,1.bb?codigoMenu=435&codigoNoticia=40046&codigoRet=18477&bread=5):

> O Módulo de Segurança é um sistema de proteção que, durante a execução de transações eletrônicas, atua como uma blindagem de seu computador contra ataques de programas maliciosos na Internet.

Em teoria, um módulo de segurança é como um mini antivírus e anti-spyware que via proteger o banco de fraudes.

## O fornecedor

Segundo algumas fontes ([veja esta](http://tecnologiaetc.net/2013/11/20/burlando-o-modulo-de-seguranca-do-banco-do-brasil/)) a empresa que fornece a tecnologia e o software tanto para o BB quando para a Caixa é a [Gas Tecnologia](http://www.gastecnologia.com.br/).

## O produto

O site desta empresa anuncia a [*solução anti-fraude para e-banking*](http://www.gastecnologia.com.br/pt/solucoes/SOLU%C3%87%C3%83O%20ANTI-FRAUDE%20PARA%20E-BANKING.htm) como "uma solução que estrutura um ambiente virtual blindado e especializado, com os requisitos necessários para a realização de transações financeiras através do canal Internet".

Algumas das funcionalidades apresentadas são:

#### *Sistema forte de identificação e autenticação de dispositivos*

Pelo menos no BB, você precisa cadastrar cada computador de onde quer acessar o site do banco.

Entretanto, costumo usar uma máquina virtual para acessar minha conta. Certa vez fiz uma cópia desta imagem para outro computador e o acesso parou de funcionar. Analisando o ocorrido, percebi que eu tinha que configurar a placa de rede da nova máquina virtual com o mesmo MAC Address da VM anterior.

#### *Análise por modelo de regas do comportamento do usuário e do end-point no canal Web e em múltiplos canais (ATM, URA, Mobile Banking)*

Talvez seja verificado se tem alguém realmente clicando nos botões ou se há um "robô" acessando o banco.

#### *Serviço diferenciado baseado no Conhecimento Sistematizado através de ferramentas e processos para analise de risco e detecção de fraudes*

Provavelmente o software tenta identificar comportamento estranho do usuário ou de processos no computador.

#### *A solução tem atuação direta sobre as deficiências e as vulnerabilidades do canal que possibilitam fraudes e violação da privacidade sobre o correntista*

A ferramenta deve tentar tratar vulnerabilidades conhecidos no sistema operacional ou nos navegadores, por exemplo.

#### *Geração de trilha de auditoria*

O sistema deve logar as atividades do usuário no site do banco. Isso possibilitaria identificar o autor de fraudes *online*.

#### *Capaz de impedir ataques massificados sobre os serviços Web*

A ferramente deve impedir acessos rápidos aos serviços, evitando [ataques de negação de serviço](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_servi%C3%A7o).

## Polêmica

[Vários](http://www.moshe.com.br/ti-cuidado-com-os-mdulos-de-segurana-bancrios/) [usuários](http://www.baboo.com.br/software/antivirus/gbbd-banco-brasil-3-0-0-google-chrome/) denunciam este módulo como um tipo de vírus ou *malware*.

Particularmente, tive uma impressão parecida. Há alguns anos meu computador apresentou períodos de instabilidade no acesso à Internet e lentidão (99% de CPU) após a instalação do Módulo de Segurança do BB. Este foi um dos motivos pelo qual decidi usar VMs.

Após instalado o módulo num computador, o usuário não consegue fechá-lo ou removê-lo. O comportamento é parecido com aqueles *malwares* que colocam vários processos. Você fecha um dos processos e ele reabre automaticamente.

Comment: Esse site tem tanto adjetivo junto que é até difícil extrair algum conteúdo! No fim, é um meio de o servidor obter o MAC (válido). De resto, parece ser um substituto temporário de um antivírus (mas sem todas as características de um, como atualização). Até agora parece ser uma falsa segurança. (um atacante poderia setar o MAC de uma VM para ser igual ao MAC do computador do usuário alvo, por exemplo). Assumir que o cliente está seguro pelo módulo parece ser um erro absurdo, esses sistemas tem de considerar o cliente como um ambiente totalmente hostil e ainda funcionar. Enfim, boa resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Exato. É como se eles prometessem o que nem  Norton, McAfee, Avast e cia. juntos conseguem fazer 100%.