# Por que determinados serviços ainda dependem do plugin do Java?

Tags: java, plugin

Bancos, certificados digitais, sites de serviços governamentais ainda dependem do *plugin* do Java.

A ideia do Java, "escreva uma vez, rode em qualquer lugar" nem sempre é uma verdade.

Muitos serviços ainda tem requerimentos específicos de plataforma, só rodam no Windows e representam um problema para usuários de outras plataformas.

O que o *plugin* do Java oferece em termos funcionais que os navegadores modernos não conseguem resolver?

Comment: Relaciondo: [O fazem os módulos de segurança comumente usados em sites de bancos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19432/91)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O principal é que estes *plugins* como o Java fornecem acesso quase irrestrito ao seu computador. Esta é grande "vantagem" de ter um aplicativo rodando Java no navegador. Pelo menos esse era o motivo no passado.

O navegador é extremamente limitado quando se trata de fazer qualquer coisa fora dele, fora desenhar uma página e fazer uma comunicação básica dentro de certos limites com o servidor onde ele está conversando naquele contexto.

Claro que é comum ter algumas limitações, esses *plugins* ainda rodam em máquinas virtuais mas a limitação é bem menor que o navegador "puro".

Além disto normalmente a linguagem e as bibliotecas disponíveis costumam ser um pouco mais poderosas dando mais ferramentas para o programador trabalhar. Isto já foi mais verdade no passado, mas ainda existe mais funcionalidade nestes *plugins*.

Também é possível conseguir melhor performance com Java ou algum *plugin* do gênero mas a escolha normalmente não é feita por causa disto.

Há uma tendência de não usar mais este tipo de recurso porque ele inclusive ajuda trazer problemas de segurança para a máquina dos seus usuários. Também muitas pessoas nem conseguem se entender com a instalação do *plugin* e ou desistem ou pagam para um técnico fazer para elas.

Se você considerar que os sites que precisam disto hoje foram substituídos por aplicativos nativos para dispositivos móveis provavelmente deveriam ter aplicativos nativos para os principais sistemas operacionais *desktop* e eliminar este tipo de necessidade. Assim ficaria no *site* apenas a funcionalidade básica que a *web* pode fornecer por padrão. E um aplicativo ainda mais poderoso e talvez mais seguro pode ser usado quando se precisa de algo mais poderoso.

Provavelmente vai dar menos problema você ter que instalar um aplicativo que o *plugin*.

Um motivo para ainda usarem o Java é porque no passado eles usavam o Java. Então não querem fazer nada de novo. Havia um motivo para usar o Java mas não há mais.

Além disto muitos programadores escolhem fazer em Java porque é o que eles sabem ou gostam. Mesmo que não precise dele especificamente, que não precise do "rodar em qualquer lugar", ele é escolhido. Isto, é claro, pode valer para qualquer linguagem ou plataforma.

Algumas pessoas acham que a filosofia do "compile uma vez em cada plataforma e rode em qualquer lugar" encontrada no C/C++ e outras linguagens é melhor e mais portável. Claro que podem existir desvantagens também.

Note que está havendo restrições a esses *plugins*, eles caíram em desuso e desde a versão 9 do Java ele é considerado depreciado e não deve ser mais usado, e o próprio Java está caminhando para outro modelo melhor que o original até mesmo quando não se tratava do *plugin*.

Answer (score 5):

O plugin do Java nada mais é do que algo que é utilizado para poder embutir applets Java em páginas de internet, semelhantemente ao que é feito com o Flash. A finalidade dele é apenas disponibilizar aplicativos Java em navegadores e não dar nenhum tipo de superpoderes aos navegadores. É verdade que antigamente os navegadores não tinham muitos recursos para fazer algumas coisas, e daí era mais fácil usar o Java ou o Flash para fazer algo que os navegadores não eram capazes (ou seja, ter os superpoderes). Mas os navegadores de hoje em dia tem plenos poderes para substituir todos ou quase todos os casos aonde o Java ou o Flash se justificariam.

A parte do "escreva uma vez, rode em qualquer lugar" é uma meia-verdade. É a ideia original e ainda tenta-se mantê-la, mas alguns acidentes no percurso quebraram isso. Um destes primeiros acidentes foi a máquina virtual Java feita pela Microsoft por volta de 1998 ou 1999, em que haviam várias classes específicas do Windows inventadas pela Microsoft dentro do pacote `java.awt` e que não existiam em outras JVMs. Isto acabou rendendo um belo processo da Sun contra a Microsoft e fez a Microsoft pular fora do Java e inventar o C#.

Outros acidentes de percurso que surgiram foram as diferenças gritantes entre o J2ME e o J2SE, como muitas classes do J2SE não existiam no J2ME e vice-versa e o J2ME tinha restrições consideráveis, o paradigma "escreva uma vez, rode em qualquer lugar" estava violado. Com a morte por inanição do J2ME e sem nada oficial ou útil vindo da Sun/Oracle para tomar o seu lugar, o Google saiu na frente e lançou o Android. Porém novamente, as diferenças significativas na API do Android para o Java SE implicam em outra quebra do paradigma "escreva uma vez, rode em qualquer lugar".

Existem mais coisas que levam a violação do paradigma, muitas delas culpa do programador. Uma forma de violar este paradigma é depender de detalhes não portáveis do sistema operacional, tal como usar de forma explícita no código caminhos como `C:\Users\Abc` no Windows ou depender do fato de `x.txt` e `X.TXT` serem dois arquivos distintos no Linux.

Outra coisa que pode levar a violação do paradigma é quando o programa em Java depende de partes feitas em código nativo que só estão disponíveis em um dado sistema operacional, ou no caso de applets Java, quando elas são feitas de forma a interagir com APIs específicas do navegador (ex: Internet Explorer).

Também há casos aonde o paradigma é violado de forma proposital, aonde o applet simplesmente se recusa a carregar se ele perceber que não está sendo executado no navegador que o desenvolvedor quis ou no sistema operacional que o desenvolvedor quis.